# auto.arima is too verbose when executing it repeatedly

Tags: r

Is there 'non-verbose' mode for `auto.arima` (`forecast` package)? When `auto.arima` executes, the following is printed. Because I'm running `auto.arima` repeatdly, it's too verbose (annoying).

```
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift                    : 13422.36
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,1)[24]                    : 13304.89
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,1)[24] with drift         : 13306.8
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,2)[24]                    : 13285.25
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,2)[24] with drift         : 13287.16
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,0)[24]                    : 13305.22
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,0)[24] with drift         : 13307.14
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,1)[24]                    : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,2)[24]                    : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,2)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,0)[24]                    : 13307.57
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,0)[24] with drift         : 13309.5
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,1)[24]                    : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,2)[24]                    : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(2,0,2)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,1)                               : 13405.68
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift                    : 13407.56
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[24]                    : 13248.82
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[24] with drift         : 13250.71
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,2)[24]                    : 13223.76
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,2)[24] with drift         : 13225.66
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)[24]                    : 13234.0
 ....
```

Comment: Did you turn `trace  = TRUE`?

Comment: @Pascal I'm so sorry. It's my fault...